# Mailcatcher/Puphpet - mail() returns false

Tags: php, puphpet

I have a virtual machine configured with puphpet, it has ubuntu 14.04, apache, php 5.6 and mailcatcher.

Once again, the title says it all. Everytime I use the mail() function it returns false. For what I can tell, there is no errors showing anywhere, which makes solving this quite difficult.

Here is the sendmail path

```
sendmail_path   /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default/catchmail -f
```

Appreciate any advice on how to solve this.

PS: I notice that the question was asked already but their are no answers accepted and the solutions proposed didn't help =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to find why it wasn't working. Although the sendmail_path is set in the zzzz_custom.ini file and in phpinfo(), it's not in fpm/php.ini file.

I just had to go to:

```
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

and set

```
sendmail_path = /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default/catchmail -f
```